# Nav bar mouseenter/mouseleave not working between li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'mm trying to design a specific type of navbar in javascript/jquery.

I cannot get `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` to work correctly when the mouse passes between the `li` objects.

Here is my code. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/richofwombwell/1v8L0pdz/38/

```
function inversebuttonon(liId, aId) {
    $(liId).css('background-color', 'white');
    $(aId).css('background-color', 'white');
    $(aId).css('color', '#0086CA');
}

function inversebuttonoff(liId, aId) {
    $(liId).css('background-color', '#0086CA');
    $(aId).css('background-color', '#0086CA');
    $(aId).css('color', 'white');
}

function showselectedmenu(liclass, aclass) {
    $('.menu').css('max-height', '100px');
    $(liclass).css('display', 'inline');
    $(aclass).css('display', 'inline');
}

function dontshowselectedmenu(liclass, aclass) {
    $('.menu').css('max-height', '0px', 'none');
    $(liclass).css('display', 'none');
    $(aclass).css('display', 'none');
}

$('#n-2').mouseenter(function () {
    inversebuttonon('#n-2', '#a2');
    showselectedmenu('.tmenuli', '.tmenua1');
});

$('.menu').mouseleave(function () {
    dontshowselectedmenu('.tmenuli', '.tmenua1');
    inversebuttonoff('#n-2', '#a2');
});

$('#n-3').mouseenter(function () {
    inversebuttonon('#n-3', '#a3');
    showselectedmenu('.tmenuli2', '.tmenua2');
}); 

$('.menu').mouseleave(function () {
    dontshowselectedmenu('.tmenuli2', '.tmenua2');
    inversebuttonoff('#n-3', '#a3');
});
```

Comment: try create [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/richofwombwell/fLqs1nru/1/

Thanks ! did put it on but it was edited out.

Comment: I think a problem is coming from your mouseleave inside of your mouseenter.  make them separate and try it then?  I think there may be a lot of reformatting you can do here to make it work, but that's a whole re-do

Comment: Thankyou !

I have edited it now outside of the mouseenter but it still is not functioning right. the mouseleave isnt working right

http://jsfiddle.net/richofwombwell/1v8L0pdz/37/

Comment: You have invalid html code, each browser may have different dom at the end. Do you really need javascript for this menus?

Comment: http://www.going-outside.co.uk/ that is the live site

Comment: The way you have it, you have in your script in the fiddle a mouseleave for the menu added every time you enter #n-3 so that is not too good

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not work correctly because your html code is invalid (you are nesting DIVs instead of list elements. That forces the browser to correct your code (the way it wants to).

Before you continue scripting, please consider using CSS solution:

```css
 * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     font-size: 16px;
}
.my_menu {
    height: 66px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:
}
.my_menu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.my_menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.my_menu > ul {
    position: relative;
    background: none #0086CA;
}
.my_menu ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}
.my_menu > ul > li > a {
    padding: 15px 20px;
}
.my_menu > ul > li > a:hover,
.my_menu > ul > li a:focus {
    color: #0086CA;
    background: #fff;
}
.my_menu ul ul {
    background: none grey;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.my_menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
.my_menu ul ul a {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.my_menu ul ul a:hover,
.my_menu ul ul a:focus {
    background: none black;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav class="my_menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">menuitem1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">menuitem2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item8</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Also at **[Playground](http://jsfiddle.net/1v8L0pdz/45/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably clean this up but if you insist on a script method, this will work: It also should be easier to extend with less id's etc. just add markup.
Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/fLqs1nru/2/

```
function showmenu(targ, me) {
    $('.menuitem').removeClass('menu-on');
    $(me).parent().addClass('menu-on');
    $('.menu').hide();
    $('.' + targ).show();
}
$('.menuitem a').mouseenter(function () {
    var targ = $(this).parent().data("targetmenu");
    showmenu(targ, this);
});
$('nav').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.menuitem ').removeClass('menu-on');
    $('.menu').hide();
});
```

Adjust the markup, get rid of the div and add some classes.  Add a data element for the target menu to use.

```
<nav>
    <ul class="ulparent">
        <li class="navitem" id="n-1"><a href="" id="a1">Home</a> 
            <li class="navitem menuitem" data-targetmenu="menu1"><a href="" id="a2">menuitem1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navitem menuitem"  data-targetmenu="menu2"><a href="#" >menuitem2</a>
            </li>
            <ul class="menu menu1">
                <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">item4</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="menu menu2">
                <li><a href="">item5</a></li>
                <li><a href="">item6</a></li>
                <li><a href="">item7</a></li>
                <li><a href="">item8</a></li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

add this to the end of you CSS (which can probably be cleaner but this is only additive:)

```
.menu-on {
    background-color: white;
}
.menu-on a {
    color:#0086CA;
}
.menu {
    max-height:100px;
    display:none;
}
```